# Xcode Show segue in Xcode 15 presents the viewcontroller as a modal

Tags: xcode, push, show, presentmodalviewcontroller, xcode15

I have a very simple setup, where when the user clicks sign up or login, it should bring them to the respected viewcontroller using the Show (e.g. Push). However, it is presented modally when the app is used on a device. Not sure what the issue could be.

It should be presented using the Show (e.g. Push) on the physical device.

[image: Xcode Screenshot][image: iPhone Screenshot]

Comment: One of two likely problems: 1. You might have `@IBAction` functions for these button in your view controller. If so, we need to see those (and please confirm that you have segue from the button or an `@IBAction`, but not both); or 2. You may have presented the `ViewController` incorrectly (somewhere presenting the `ViewController` instead of the navigation controller that has the `ViewController` embedded in it).

Comment: There is not enough here for us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: BTW, check out “View Debugger” in [Diagnosing issues in the appearance of a running app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-issues-in-the-appearance-of-your-running-app). That will help you confirm that the navigation controller is in the view hierarchy.